# club multiple arrays into an associate array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to club multiple arrays into a single associate array

like

```
$big=array(
1=>$simpleArray1,
2=>$simpleArray2,
3=>$singleArray3
);
```

I know that the above way of assignment is wrong, it does not actually club the arrays. Please recommend me the best way. Thanks :)

**EDIT**

**All those arrays have same keys**, so how I should proceed ahead in this case. I understand that keys are meant to be identical, but what do I do now! I'm confused because I need to club `n` number of arrays with different volumes of data in each

Comment: What is _club_? it sounds quite aggressive =)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen
club=mixing of

Comment: you mean `merge`? Try `array_merge`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to merge arrays?

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

**EDIT**

> All those arrays have same keys, so how I should proceed ahead in this
>   case. I understand that keys are meant to be identical, but what do I
>   do now! I'm confused because I need to club n number of arrays with
>   different volumes of data in each

So how do you want it to look?

you can do also

```
$all = array();
$all[] = $firstarray;
$all[] = $secondarray;
$all[] = $thirdarray;

but than you must do twice foreach, and you cannot search by id
foreach($all as $arr){
 foreach($arr as $item){
  echo $item["name"];
 }
}
```

Main question is, what do you want to do with the aggregate array.
if you do not care about the keys the worst case scenario is

```
$arr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $v){$arr[] = $v;}
foreach($arr2 as $v){$arr[] = $v;}
foreach($arr3 as $v){$arr[] = $v;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge($arr1, $arr2, ...)`.
See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and notice that identical keys will be overwritten by the latest ones.